# when the first datagram is received, recvfrom() doesn't fill the structur `sockaddr`

Tags: c, network-programming

I have two machines A and B in LAN
I have a UDP client on  A
and a UDP server on B, like

```
for(;;){
    n = recvfrom(sockfd, mesg, 10000, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);
    ....}
```

I notice when the UDP client sends the first datagram
I can get the datagram data payload through `mesg` correctly
but the structure `cliaddr` is not filled, it is with the original value
e.g, if I use `bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));`,
in `gdb`, I got

```
$1 = {sin_family = 0, sin_port = 0, sin_addr = {s_addr = 0}, sin_zero = 
 "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}
```

what is the reason when the first datagram is received, recvfrom() doesn't fill the structure `cliaddr`?

for the sebsequent datagram, the valid info can be obtained.

Comment: Do subsequent datagrams contain valid info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before calling `recvfrom` you must properly initialize the `len` argument.

E.g.

```
len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
n = recvfrom(..., &len);
```

The `recvfrom` function uses the length to help determine what kind of structure the `sockaddr` pointer actually points to.